# border right style not extending down with accordion

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I created a html page with an accordion in one div and a menu in another div element. The menu div has a simple border styling on the right of the element using

```
height:100%;
 border-right-width:2px;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-color:#4875B4;
```

This all works nicely, however, whenever I expand an accordion header the border does not expand also(I thought it would as height is set to 100%). I can't use border style on accordion cause in the code I'm using I hide it as default.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxnAd/ 
JSFiddle
Please select "section 3" to see the border not extending with accordion

Comment: Why not put the border on the accordion ? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxnAd/13/)

Comment: Why dont you add a border to the `pane`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve your problem

**First**

Remove the `right border` from `#menus` and apply the `left border` to `div.accordion`

like

```
.accordion {border-left:2px solid #F00;}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/ZxnAd/14/

**Second**

By using `js` you have to find the `height` of the `accordion` and apply that `height` to `div#menus` on `click event` of `accordion div` like,

```
$('div#menus').height($('div.accordion').height());
```

**But** this will create problems may be you need to change your **HTML structure**

So, I think the `first one` is `good` for you.

Comment: Hi Rohan, I want to use your second solution, however, whenever I click on an accordion header it picks up the height before the click. This results, in the border being long when collapsing a header.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean this with your question:

replace your CSS with:

```
.accordion {
 position:absolute;
 color: #AAA;
 //title-background:black;
 top:0;
 left:195px;
 padding: 0px;
 width:100%;
}
```

It makes the border 100% of the div to the right

Border around the menus:

```
#menus{
 position:absolute;
 top:2px;
 left:0;
 width:190px;
 height:100%;
 border-style:solid;
 border-right-width:2px;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-color:#119900;

}
```

Comment: and if you want the background image to fill it: instead of no-repeat make it repeat

Comment: Sorry, I want a border on the 'Menu' div, not the accordion, as the accordion is hidden on load in my source

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve it. When you expand 'section 3', then scroll down the page, you will see that the border has not gone down to the bottom

Comment: I guess you need some jquery for that. Since it still is 100%. But section 3 gets beneath the 100% and makes a new 100% height what css won't see.